# error cursor don't close Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

first to say is that the app works well, but the log have an error with this cursor:

```
public Cursor getDiff() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sacaDif = "SELECT dificultad FROM " + people;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sacaDif, null);
        return c;
    }
```

I know it's because I don't close it, but I can't close the cursor before or after sending it...

This is the log file:

```
05-30 14:48:16.011: D/dalvikvm(363): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4814 objects / 256176 bytes in 100ms
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.example.proyecto008almacenardatossharedpreferences/databases/administracion, table = null, query = SELECT dificultad FROM dificultad
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at com.example.proyecto008almacenardatossharedpreferences.CreaTablas.getDiff(CreaTablas.java:47)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at com.example.proyecto008almacenardatossharedpreferences.Opciones.onCreate(Opciones.java:25)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-30 14:48:16.039: E/Cursor(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what can I do to stop this error?
Thank you

Comment: did you never called close() on your cursor?

Comment: Why not returning data instead of the cursor?

Comment: if I do c.close() before the sending it doesn't work..
I'll try to return data

Comment: the problem is solved, i did that @Seraphim said.
Thank you!

Comment: @user2433216 click it if you find it useful ;) always happy to help!

Comment: it wasn't an answer, was a comment, i can't click anything :(

Answer (score 1):

Store data in pojo class object and return instead of returning cursor.  It's a best practice.

Comment: thank you for the help, I know that the pojo class is the best solution, but it is a little application and it isn't necessary ;)